# funcion JS solo funciona al dar dos click

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de validar un formulario pero solo lo valida cuando presiono dos veces el botón, MI FUNCION:

```js
  $( "#formcambio" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var password = document.getElementById("password")
      , confirm_password = document.getElementById("password2");
      if(password.value !== confirm_password.value) {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
      } else {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
      }
   
      });
```

```html
<form method="post" id="formcambio">
            <h2 class="text-center"><strong>Cambio de Contraseña</strong></h2>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" id="pass-act" placeholder="Contraseña Actual" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña nueva" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" id="password2" placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" style="background-color: #4784f4;">Guardar Contraseña</button></div></form>
```

Comment: podrias poner el HTML del boton?

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" style="background-color: #4784f4;">Guardar Contraseña</button>`

Comment: El primero es para darle foco y el segundo es para ejecutarlo, también funciona con un Enter, aunque veo que tienes razón habrá que pensar una alternativa, como pasarle el foco con tab y después dar enter o barra espaciadora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error se da porque quieres usar metodos de la clase jquery desde fuera de esta es decir jquery y javascript
puedes validar esto usando `document.getElementByid("selector")` seguido de una funcion jquery por ello `document` o `window` etc se utilizan dentro de `$()`

**tu codigo:**

```js
  $( "#formcambio" ).on("change",function( event ) {
       // event.preventDefault();
        let password = document.getElementById("password");
        let confirm_password = document.getElementById("password2");
      if(password.value !== confirm_password.value) {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
      } else {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
      }
   
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="formcambio">
            <h2 class="text-center"><strong>Cambio de Contraseña</strong></h2>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" id="pass-act" placeholder="Contraseña Actual" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña nueva" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" id="password2" placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña" required></div>
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" style="background-color: #4784f4;">Guardar Contraseña</button></div></form>
```

Comment: me aparece el error `"Uncaught TypeError: confirm_password.setCustomValidity is not a function"`

Comment: ya corregi jquery return array elements!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto te podría servir.

```
$("#formcambio").submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var password = $("#password")[0];
    var password2 = $("#password2")[0];
    password2.setCustomValidity(password.value == password2.value ? "" : "Passwords Don't Match");
    $("#formcambio")[0].reportValidity()
})
```